# Angular ChartJS 2.9.4 issue updating chart

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I'm facing an issue updating Chart (ver 2.9.4) in Angular 9+, Although I can create new chart instance with `new Chart(ctx, config)` but not able to update it. I got **ERROR TypeError: chart.update is not a function**

Reference: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/developers/updates.html?h=update

Below is my code

**ReportComponent.html**

```
<canvas #chart style="width: 100%; height: 480px;">{{chart}}</canvas>

<button (click)="generateReport()">Generate</button>
<button (click)="updateReport()">Update</button>
```

**ReportComponent.ts**

```
export class ReportDashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
    @ViewChild('chart', { static: false }) chartRef: ElementRef;
    chart: Chart;
    dataSource: any;

    constructor(
        private reportService: ReportService,
    ) {}

    generateReport() {
        if ( this.dataSource ) {
          this.chart = this.reportService.init(this.chartRef, this.dataSource);
        }
    }

    updateReport() {
        if ( this.dataSource ) {
          this.reportService.update(this.chartRef, this.dataSource);
        }
    }
}
```

**ReportService.ts**

```
import { Chart, ChartConfiguration, ChartOptions, ChartData } from 'chart.js';

export class ReportService {
    chart: Chart;

    constructor() { }

    init(chartRef: ElementRef, data: UniChartData): Chart {
        const ctx = chartRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
        const config = this.getConfig(data);

        return new Chart(ctx, config);
    }

    update(chart: Chart, data: any): void {
        if (!chart) { return; }

        chart.config = this.getConfig(data);
        chart.update();
    }
}
```

I've tried with multiple approaches but no luck so far. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you upload it to stackbliz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass the chart object instead of the ElementRef to the update function of your service and it should work...

```
updateReport() {
        if ( this.dataSource ) {
          this.reportService.update(this.chart, this.dataSource);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Siddharth, It looks like working as expected now.